Audio to Video Conversion using FFmpeg in React
Upon running my code, the audio successfully gets converted into a video and saved in the bucket, however, the video size is just 9 bytes.
Here's my utility.
import { FFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
import { fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/util';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { storage } from '../firebase'; 

export async function generateAndStoreVideo(audioPath, imagePath, userId) {
  try {
    const ffmpeg = new FFmpeg({ log: true });
    await ffmpeg.load();

    console.log('Fetching audio and image...');
    ffmpeg.writeFile( 'input.mp3', await fetchFile(audioPath));
    ffmpeg.writeFile('input.jpg', await fetchFile(imagePath));
    
    console.log('Running FFmpeg...');
    await ffmpeg.exec(['-i', 'sound.mp3', '-i', 'image.png', 'output.mp4']
    );

    console.log('FFmpeg completed!');
    
    const data = ffmpeg.readFile( 'output.mp4');
    const videoBlob = new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' });

    console.log('Uploading video to Firebase...');
    const videoRef = ref(storage, `videos/${userId}/${Date.now()}_generated_video.mp4`);
    const uploadSnapshot = await uploadBytes(videoRef, videoBlob);

    const videoURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadSnapshot.ref);

    console.log('Video uploaded successfully! URL:', videoURL);

    return videoURL;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating or uploading video:', error);
    throw new Error('Video generation or upload failed.');
  }
}


After uploading, I also got this error:
ErrnoError: FS error
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:98427:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:98450:7

I've made sure I'm using the new FFMPEG version and syntax, but the issues persist.

If you're running this on a backend, you shouldn't use "firebase/storage" at all.  That's intended for web frontends running in the browser.  For backends, you should instead use the Firebase Admin SDK (or @google-cloud/storage) to work with Cloud Storage.

@DougStevenson i'm not using this in backend

Are you sure? You can't directly read and write files in a filesystem from code running in a browser.  That's strictly forbidden for the safety of the end user.  Otherwise, malicious browser code could read data that the user didn't authorize.
